# Eclipse MAT thread attributes

Tags: heap-dump, eclipse-mat

I have Liferay 6.1.2 CE application deployed to Jboss EAP 6.4
I am trying to analyze heap dump using Eclipse MAT after server crashed by OOM.

In dominator tree I see couple of threads that occupying a lot of memory.
[image]

My question what do parkBlocker and other Treads Attributes mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'parkBlocker' is a field name of java.lang.Thread. Attribute here means field name.
The actual use of a field depends on the code, but my guess is that is the object used to block on when a thread is parked(). See the park*() methods on java.lang.Thread.